# Email-Details ( body part) are not showing when creating an Email putting email server id in Bcc

Tags: c#, .net, email, bcc

I am unable to see  Email-Details ( body part) when I put an email server id in "Bcc" and also while inserting that email in table , BCC field is showing "NULL".
can anyone help?

Comment: Can you please specify .. where (means using Outlook, chrome browser) you trying??

Comment: In my own e-mail product. Thanks.

Comment: Using which technology? php?.net?c++?

Comment: .net with c# . . n sql as backend. . thnx.

Comment: `when I put an email server id in "Bcc"` what it means by email server id?can you please edit your question and put some code on it .. for more clearity..